# python webbrowser

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I've been using this module without problems by calling it as:

```
webbrowser.open("http link...")
```

now, however, I wanted to select a different browser, and according to the docs (http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.get) I wrote this

```
controller = webbrowser.get('firefox')
controller("http link...")
```

... and I get an error I'm unable to get rid of:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
TypeError: 'Mozilla' object is not callable
```

any idea about it???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [Controller object](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects) is not callable. Do this:

```
controller.open(url)
```